# how to decrease relative distance between geom_point() in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a graph that shows a lot of information and I don't want to waste space on whitespace. Is there any way to decrease the plotted distance between points on the x axis. Ideally, I want them to almost touch. I can probably do that changing absolutely every size parameter (dots, axis labels, annotations, legend entries etc) in the plot to something huge but I was wondering if there is an easier way to do so along the lines of position.dodge or so?

Here is an example saved in two different sizes to show that they still have high relative distance:

```
library(ggplot)

plotdata <- data.frame(my_y = rnorm(3),
                       my_x = 1:3)

pdf("yourpath/test.pdf",
    width = 4, height = 4)
ggplot(plotdata, aes(x = my_x, y = my_y)) + geom_point()
dev.off()

pdf("yourpath/test2.pdf",
    width = 2, height = 2)
ggplot(plotdata, aes(x = my_x, y = my_y)) + geom_point()
dev.off()
```

Comment: Is the x-axis continuous or categorical?

Comment: continuous but I can easily change this to categorical

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My answer takes a similar approach to @Quinten but builds in a function for any data:

```
xmax<-max(plotdata$my_x);ymax=max(plotdata$my_y)
xmin<-min(plotdata$my_x);ymin=min(plotdata$my_y)

pdf("C:/temp/test.pdf",
   width = 4, height = 4)
ggplot(plotdata, aes(x = my_x, y = my_y)) + geom_point()+
  xlim(xmin-0.1,xmax+0.1)+
  ylim(ymin-0.1,ymax+0.1)

dev.off()
```

Comment: this has the added advantage to work with other coord_... like coord_flip(), right? Could you elaborate on what is happening here? You're setting the limits of where things are plotted without changing the limits of the entire plot?

Comment: This will hold when `coord_flip()` is applied. My solution does change the plot limits, but just barely.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, you can set limits in `coord_cartesian`. First plot without limits:

```
ggplot(plotdata, aes(x = my_x, y = my_y)) + geom_point()
```

Output:

[image]

With limits:

```
ggplot(plotdata, aes(x = my_x, y = my_y)) + geom_point() + coord_cartesian(xlim=c(-1, 3),
                                                                           ylim=c(-1.5, 0.5))
```

Output:

[image]

As you can see, they are shown closer together.

Comment: Word of warning: `coord_cartesian` will not produce a warning when points are not included, where as setting the limits with `lims`(or the `scale_x_*` family) will produce a warning when points are excluded.

Comment: this answer works perfectly fine for my example (I chose the other answer because I have the feeling it is more flexible for more complicated examples)